htaccess ErrorDocument rule is not respecting broken URLs ending with ".php" extension
I need help with something too simple or so complex that it will break the website I'm working on. I will be as concise and brief as possible to explain the problem.

The website uses a simple php call function (echo) to inject repetitive sections into the HTML code. The entire website is static, except for the blog section hosted on WordPress.

Now, for that purpose, every file on the server is named like this - mywebsite.com/file1.php

I have implemented basic rewrite rules in htaccess for forced www. & https, some 301 redirects for pages that got their URL changed, and a custom 404 page for handling nonexistent URLs.


The Problem
Every broken link is getting redirected (EDIT: By redirected i meant showing the custom error document with Status code 404) as indented except those ending with .php at the end.
For e.g:

https: //www. mywebsite.com/broken.asp (GETS REDIRECTED AS INTENDED)
https: //www. mywebsite.com/broken.html (GETS REDIRECTED AS INTENDED)
https: //www. mywebsite.com/broken (GETS REDIRECTED AS INTENDED)
https: //www. mywebsite.com/broken.php (FILE NOT FOUND)

Every broken URL and manual redirection works fine except for non-existent URLs ending with .php. It shows Status Code 404 and a blank page showing "File Not Found." Every other broken URL gives Status codes 404 and gets redirected to custom 404 page. Now, this would not be so bothering if it weren't for SEO; this is making 404 errors pop up like crazy for pages I deleted for website redesign (lots and lots of them).
The Fixes I Tried
1.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/404.php [L,R=301]

This gives Code: 302 for every broken page but custom Redirect 301 stops working and everything gets redirected to 404. 
2.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ /index.php [L,R=404]

I tried this one, thinking non-existent .php urls will get redirected to homepage but it yields the same effect for custom Redirect 301
3.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php

Now, this one works like a charm for both non-existent .php URLs and custom 301 redirects, but it is giving Status Code 200 for each broken link, which IMO is very bad for SEO POV.
I tried everything and now am at my wit's end. I even contacted the server people where the website is hosted, only to get the answer "This is beyond our scope, and requires attention from web designer".
Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. 

Current .htaccess as requested
RewriteEngine On
# Forced www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Enable HSTS Header - Forces browsers to always use HTTPS to access your site.
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

# Disables website embedding in iframe from everywhere but itself.
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

# Browser Caching - Improve site speed by setting expiration times for static resources
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 6 months"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

# Gzip Compression - Compress text-based content to improve page load time.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json application/xml
</IfModule>

# Cache-Control Headers - Almost Same as Browser Caching but more refined - Works well with browser caching
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|webp)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Prevent Hotlinking Of Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?mydomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)$ - [F,NC]

# Block Spammy Bots and Scrappers from eating out the bandwidth
SetEnvIf User-Agent "AbuseBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIf User-Agent "BadBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIf User-Agent "spambot" bad_bot
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot

# Prevent Directory Listing - already active through server, change - to + to enable it.
Options -Indexes

# Compress css, js, text, etc for faster loading
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate"
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php

# 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 ...... (Some Redirects)

# Handling non-existent .php files after the manual redirects
# This code is making every broken URL Status Code: 200 Currently Commented in the live file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php


***One More thing I don't want to drop .php from my live URLs due to SEO dependency.*** 

Please show us your full .htaccess file, including all that stuff you are talking about under 3.)

@C3roe Done updated the question and added the current live rules.

You are explicitly rewriting every request for a non-existing file or folder to your index.php, when the requested URL ends in .php

This was a desperate attempt, if I remove the rule 3, which BTW is currently not active, the case remains the same, Errordocument rule work for every other broken URL in the world except the one ending with .php at the end.

"if I remove the rule 3" - you are referring to that whole last block, correct? Redirect 301 ...... (Some Redirects) - are you absolutely sure, those don't interfere somehow? (Keep in mind, that Redirect only does prefix matching on the URL path.)

No just the rule 3, I need manual 301 redirects. There some pages with good authority that got its URL changed. Redirect 301 is used for such "now" non-existent urls. And they are working if and only if rule 3 is removed.

"Rule 3", if we count from the top, would be the one that handles image hotlinking. I was asking, did you remove everything after the # Handling non-existent .php files after the manual redirects comment, or - what, exactly?

"Redirect 301 is used for such "now" non-existent urls. And they are working if and only if rule 3 is removed." - then whatever you redirected to, probably still gets matched by your rewriting in the next request. So please show what you are actually doing there, at least some examples.

Sorry my bad, I was referring to rule 3 of The Fixes I tried from the question. Yes I removed  everything after. '# Handling non-existent .php files after the manual redirects'.

For sake of testing I kept only forced www and https rule, errordocument rule, and one 301 redirect rule. Non-existent URL ending with .php are still not redirecting and giving out status code 404.

Then that is probably due to configuration on the server level, which means your hoster would need to help with clarifying things.

Haha Then it's a loop because hoster has told me it's beyond their scope, I appreciate your interest in helping me. Thanks.

After a lot of discussions and serious chats with my hosting provider, I was unable to get a proper resolution from them, they keep saying it is out of their scope, and, it's the responsibility of my web designer to sort out this error. So I took it upon myself and got a temporary fix from Chat-GPT 4o. I'm posting the rule below for open critique. The following rule satisfies all my current need viz. Non-existent URLs ending with .php is giving 404 with custom Error page, manual 301 Redirects are working as intended, & there is no "file not found" error.
# 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /old-page.php /new-page.php
 
### This is CHATGPT Magic
# Custom 404 for .php files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404.php [L,R=404]
 
# General 404 for non-.php URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404.php [L,R=404]

Now only thing I really want is the explanation of why I was having file not found page rather than URL not found/custom 404 page. I think it is something related to PHP routing, but, as a non-expert, I'm not sure the exact cause.
Cheers!
